# Alterar Title para exibir tooltip

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou fazendo validação do e-mail usando toolTip  para exibir a mensagem. Se de primeira o cara põe e-mail cadastrado a busca é feita e exibida a mensagem de que o "E-mail Cadastrado", se ele alterar o e-mail para um que não seja cadastrado a mensagem deveria ser "E-mail disponível", mas mesmo que ele troque o e-mail para disponível a mensagem permanece. como faço para que seja alterada? Obs: se a forma for diferente (e-mail disponível) a mensagem é exibida dizendo que o e-mail é disponível, e se ele alterar para um que exista a mensagem "E-mail disponível" é mantida. Então meu problema esta sendo no title.

```
    //validação de email
    $(function validateEmail() {
        $('#Email').change(function () {
            var url = '@Url.Action("ValidateEmail", "Ajax")';//url do controller que passará a informação
            var email = $('#Email').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: { email: email },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success==true) {
                        $('.messageTooltip').tooltip({ title: "Email já cadastrado" });
                        //$('#MensagemEmail').text("Email Já Cadastrado");
                        $('#Email').focus();
                    }
                    if (data.success == false) {
                        $('.messageTooltip').tooltip({ title: "Email disponível" });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });//Fim da validação de email
```

Como pode ser visto na imagem a baixo, o retorno está sendo executado corretamente, sendo que no primeiro foi inserido um e-mail não cadastrado, e no segundo cadastrado.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem certeza que que o `success` é falso em determinado momento? E a segunda condição semânticamente é desnecessária, ficaria melhor somente com `else`.

Comment: Está sim, como pode ver na imagem que coloquei agora sobre ter colocado if no lugar do else, foi pq eu estava testando mesmo, tinha feito com else.

Comment: Tu já viu se tá entrando no segundo if? colocar um console.log lá e faz o teste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para alterar o tooltip você pode fazer assim que funciona ^^, ele se perde do jeito que você esta fazendo.

```js
$('#batata').tooltip({ title: "Email já cadastrado" })

setTimeout(function(){
  $('#batata').attr("data-original-title", "batata")
},3000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<br><br>
<br><br>
<br><br>
<input id="batata" />
```